# Powershell get lastlogonDate of all servers in OU

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, export-to-csv

I am trying to get the last logonDate of all servers in OU with Powershell.

My script is able to collect the data but unable to write it to the csv report. (The current version populates only the Server name and not the OS and LogonDate fields in the csv file)
Need help with adjusting the output and if you can suggest improvements would also be great

```bsh
$allservers = get-adcomputer -filter * -searchbase "ou=important, ou=Member Servers, dc=contoso, dc=com" | select-object -expand name
$File = "$(Get-Date -Format ddMMyy_HHmmss)"

foreach ($server in $allservers) {
    Get-ADComputer -Identity $server -Properties * | format-table Name, LastLogonDate, OperatingSystem 
    $Props = [ordered]@{
        ServerName      = $server
        OperatingSystem = $server.OperatingSystem
        LastLogonDate   = $server.LastLogonDate
    }

    $Obj = New-Object psobject -Property $Props
    $obj | Export-Csv -Path .\$File.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -Append
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you think that the first call in the foreach block is actually doing something with the `$server` variable. You are indeed loading all the properties from AD, but they are only printed to the console with `Format-Table`, not assigned to `$server`.

If you change second `Get-ADComputer` call to this, it will work.
Replace

```bsh
Get-ADComputer -Identity $server -Properties * | format-table Name, LastLogonDate, OperatingSystem
```

with this:

```bsh
$server = Get-ADComputer -Identity $server -Properties * 
$server | format-table Name, LastLogonDate, OperatingSystem
```

However, I would probably replace the entire thing with this, which will do the same:

```bsh
$File = "$(Get-Date -Format ddMMyy_HHmmss)"
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "ou=important, ou=Member Servers, dc=contoso, dc=com" -Properties LastLogonDate,OperatingSystem | 
    Select-Object DistinguishedName, LastLogonDate, OperatingSystem | 
    Export-Csv -Path .\$File.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```